# Is there any problem to my solution for Problem 2.3.9 in pinter's set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem 9.
Let $f:A\rightarrow C$ and $g:A\rightarrow B$ be functions. Prove that there exists a function $h:B\rightarrow C$ such that $f=h\circ g $ if and only if  $\forall x,y\in A$

$$g(x)=g(y) \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$$

Prove that $h$ is unique.

$(\Rightarrow)$
$g(x)=g(y)\Rightarrow h(g(x))=h(g(y))\Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$

$(\Leftarrow)$
Let 
$$h(y)=\Big{\{}^{f(x)\; if \; y\in g(A)\;\And\; g(x)=y}_{z_1\in C\; if\; y\in B-g(A)}$$

Actually this function satisfy the suggestion in problem

$$h(y)=\Big{\{}^{f(x)\; if \; y\in g(A)\;\And\; g(x)=y}_{z_2\in C\; if\; y\in B-g(A)}$$
is also satisfy above, so $h$ is not unique, I don't know what is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's extra information, there's no reason to think $h$ will be unique. Assume $x\in B$ and $y\in C$, and let $f(a)=y$ and $g(a)=x$ for all $a\in A$. Then if $B$ and $C$ both have more than one element, it's easy to see there will be more than one such $h$.

TL;DR - The question as presented here is flawed; $h$ needn't be unique.

Comment: The matter is quite different if $g$ is required to be surjective, and perhaps this is what the exercise was intended to be. But I think the exercise as it appears in the text is ill posed.